# fast matrix sum in Octave/MATLAB?

Tags: matrix, sum, octave

I have a potentially big matrix in octave, say

```
N = 1e6; my_matrix = rand(1e3, N);
```

and a list of column indices:

```
column_indices = randsample(N,N/2);
```

What I want is exactly

```
sum(my_matrix(:, column_indices), 2);
```

but this can be slow for big N's (3 sec. on my PC with a big bump in the RAM). Octave/MATLAB calculates `my_matrix(:, column_indices)` first, which takes time and memory, and then sums. Any way octave can do this faster? (Perhaps by avoiding creating the matrix `my_matrix(:, column_indices)`? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use matrix multiplication:

```
column_indices = randsample(N,N/2);
idx = zeros(N,1);
idx(column_indices) = 1;

result = my_matrix * idx;
```

Here each row is multiplied by a binary vector without creating a temporary huge matrix.

Comment: Yes , it is the same as `sum(my_matrix .* idx.', 2);` but without creating a temporary.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know what I didn't think of that. That works great.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're looking for a fast solution in Octave. I don't have Octave here to test with, but for MATLAB a loop is quite a bit faster:

```
function res = sumcols(mat, column_indices)
res = mat(:,column_indices(1));
for ii = 2:numel(column_indices)
   res = res + mat(:, column_indices(ii));
end
```

I tested it with an array somewhat smaller than your example:

```
N = 1e5; my_matrix = rand(1e3, N);
column_indices = randi(N, N/2, 1);

timeit(@()sum(my_matrix(:, column_indices), 2))       % 0.2697 s
timeit(@()sumcols(my_matrix, column_indices))         % 0.0446 s
```

For this size array, a loop is 6 times faster.

We can also sort the column indices:

```
timeit(@()sum(my_matrix(:, sort(column_indices)), 2)) % 0.2623 s
```

This changes the output ever so slightly (the floating-point rounding errors change by changing the order of summation), but also speeds up computation ever so slightly because we're accessing data in the right order.

On Octave all these timings will be very different. It is possible that the `sort` has a larger influence on the output for you, and it is possible that the loop slows things down instead of speeding them up. Please test and share your results with us!

Comment: On my version of Octave (4.2.1), `sumcols` takes over twice as long as `sum`. The JIT compiler in Octave is experimental and turned off by default. In fact, it's not even built into the distribution I have, so I can't test if JIT speeds up the loop any.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that made my code faster. That came at a surprise to me since I thought vectorialising was always the way to go. I ended up implemented rahnema1's solution as it is even faster.